# Disabling Bluetooth and IVP6 in Lubuntu 14.04 does not work

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth

The method I utilized to disable Bluetooth and IVP6 in Lubuntu 13.10 apparently does not work in Lubuntu 14.04. Attempted three times and all three times I could not even boot to Desktop. Error messages.

In 13.10 I did the following:

sudo gksudo leafpad /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

blacklist ipv6

blacklist rfcomm

blacklist bnep

blacklist btusb

blacklist bluetooth

sudo gksudo leafpad /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf

## Disable Bluetooth

alias net-pf-31 off

The above method worked fine in 13.10. When I attempt the same method in 14.04 I get error messages upon boot that the entries are being ignored. However the screen just stays frozen on the messages. When I do a cold reboot and go into recovery mode, choose root and attempt to remove the entries I get an error message stating that leafpad cannot be accessed or something to that effect. So I have to start over again with a clean install.

Please advise if possible. Maybe IVP6 and Bluetooth cannot be disabled in 14.04? Is there a way to prevent start-up of both rather than a full disable?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use sysctl configuration to disable IPv6.   I don't have bluetooth configured, but there may be parameters for it as well.  Try `sysctl -a` to get a list of parameters.

This is the contents of my `/etc/sysctl.d/80-disable-ipv6.conf`. I have IPv6 enabled, so the settinges are commented out.

```
# 80-disable-ipv6.conf

#net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 0

#net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.lo.use_tempaddr = -1

# EOF
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will try the contents you provided. I attempted a sixth time to operate Lubuntu 14.04 and, without doing any changes at all, I accessed the LXTerminal and got the following error messages: 1) sudo: command not found  2) sudo leafpad: command not found  3) sudo apt-get: command not found. I get the same error messages typing the commands in the Grub Recovery Mode (root). For example sudo leafpad /etc/default/grub come back with error message: sudo leafpad: command not found

Comment: @user236378 The command not found message indicate that the program is either not installed, or is not on the search path.  In this case it appears the missing command is `sudo`.  Try running `sudo -i` to verify.